# Install Wordpress out of www/html Folder

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, apache, single-page-application, wordpress-rest-api

i want to have a single page application that uses wordpress rest api by using angular. i installed the angular application inside **/var/www/html** folder. but knowing this fact that nobody should have access to wordpress publicly where should i install wordpress? is it ok to install it somewhere like **/var/www/html/wordpress** folder? i have an ubuntu VPS with apache2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can install WordPress inside any folder ,wordpress automatically create site_Url and site path according to your installing folder. But out of Apache root folder you can't since WordPress is based on PHP code ,Apache needed to run the server scripting language(PHP ) .Inside /var/www/html/../.../.../wordpress any folder you can

Comment: of course we can install anywhere inside html folder but the question is can we "out of html folder"? is it possible to install it out of there?

Comment: is it ok to install it somewhere like /var/www/html/wordpress folder?  yes 
 But out of Apache root folder you can't since WordPress is based on PHP code ,Apache needed to run the server scripting language(PHP ) .Inside   /var/www/html/../.../.../wordpress  any folder you can